# Making a loop continue going until user leaves the page?

Tags: jquery, loops, animation, slideshow, infinite

Basically I made a little slideshow (don't know what else to call it) with Jquery on my website and I want it to keep looping through the animations until the user leaves the page?
Here is my Jquery code

```
var t2 = setTimeout(function(){
$("#wantawebsite").delay(500).fadeIn(1000).delay(9500).fadeOut(1000);

$("#dontwanttopay").delay(1500).slideDown(1000).delay(8500).fadeOut(1000);

$("#thisistheplace").delay(3000).fadeIn(1000).delay(7000).fadeOut(1000);

$("#slideshowmonitor").delay(3300).fadeIn(1000).delay(6700).fadeOut(1000);

$( "#span1" ).delay(700).effect( "bounce", "slow" );

$( "#span2" ).delay(2300).effect( "bounce", "slow" );

$(".order").delay(2800).fadeIn(1000).delay(7200).fadeOut(1000);


}, 500);
var t3 = setTimeout(function(){
$("#werehiring").delay(500).fadeIn(1000).delay(9500).fadeOut(1000);

$("#applicationtext").delay(1500).slideDown(1000).delay(8500).fadeOut(1000);

$(".contactbutton").delay(3000).fadeIn(1000).delay(7000).fadeOut(1000);

$("#imageslide2").delay(3500).fadeIn(1000).delay(6500).fadeOut(1000);

  $(".contact").delay(2800).fadeIn(1000).delay(7300).fadeOut(1000);
}, 12500);
```

How exactly would I do this? Since making an infinite loop will just crash browser obviously.

Comment: _"making an infinite loop will just crash browser"_ - An infinite loop in the sense of `while(true){}` will lock up the browser. But a timeout-based "pseudo-loop" is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your animation as chain of callbacks, like this

```
$('#book').fadeIn(1000, function() {
   // next animation
});
```

Comment: Sorry for nooby question, how would I call it? I am working on learning the language fully.